# Helvetica font only corrupted in Chrome on OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fonts, file-corruption

For the past few weeks, Helvetica has been corrupted whenever I use Chrome v23.0.1271.91 on OS X. I tested it in Firefox and any pages that use this font display properly.

I used AppZapper to uninstall Chrome and also deleted all files in ~/Library/Caches/ as well as ~/Application Support/Google/ to do a fresh install, but the issue is still occurring.

I tried using Font Book to restore standard fonts, but the issue persists.

Here's an example of what I see in Chrome:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: It seems to already been asked: http://superuser.com/questions/521363/helvetica-neue-font-error-boxed-characters-on-google-chrome-for-mac?rq=1